# Preencher campo CPF + Data com mascara selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

Estou com dificuldade para preencher campos de Data e CPF com mascara através do id ou xpth no selenium+java+JUnit.

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer?.

OBS.: Não quero gerar CPF...quero preencher campo.

Comment: Se o campo já tem a mascara que formata o cpf então não tem mistério, basta você enviar um sendkeys("cpf"); para ele e pronto, ele ira preencher numa boa.